# VS2017 code changes not affecting .exe file

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, release

So I have a problem facing VS code changes.

Whatever changes I have applied to my solution and built, it is working fine and I can see those changes being applied when I debug. **But** the same changes aren't applying to the `.exe` file.

I have tried release build as well, Same with that. It Debugs the release build fine but doesn't apply those changes to the `.exe` file.

Comment: You use VS or VScode? How many projects are there in your current solution? Please try rebuilding the solution in both debug and release mode to check if it makes any difference.

Comment: i'm using vs 2017 ... not code.... there are 4 projects .....i have tried building in both modes... debugging works fine in both and the .exe file also get modified (i mean the date and time in the folder view) , but i do not see the changes in the application whatsoever

Comment: you need to show us a bit more details. For instance building a [mcve] would be helpful fo ryou as much as for potential answerers. (For instance, a very simple console application, just to demonstrate).
Also, when you build, the exe will go to different folder depending on the build configuration (check "Debug" as well as "Release" bin folders).
Also, maybe there are dependencies that are not rebuilt. Try "Rebuild all", and "Clean", which should force the dll (other projects that are referenced) to be rebuilt, when you build the "main" (exe) application.

Comment: Also, there can be some subtelties regarding compilation of constants. For instance : if you change a value of a constant in a project, and it is used in another project, then the other project needs to be recompiled after the change. Constants are not "referenced" by the main project, they are litterally copied into other projects for compilation,

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue?  Before debugging, rebuild the whole solution, and share more details about your project type, programming language, and the code changes you mean.Like Pac0 suggests, it's better to provide a minimal reproducible example if possible :)

Comment: so guys thank you so much for the help.... i figured it out... had to rebuild all like you suggested.... still didnt work, but once i deleted the existing .exe file and rebuilt all again , it worked .... thank you lance and pac0

Comment: UPDATE: basically, go  to Build--> Batch Build--> click Select all --> clean it first --> then build.... it should work fine .... and before you do all this, put it in release mode and do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It Debugs the release build fine but doesn't apply those changes to
>   .exe file.

When you debug the project, `VS debug engine will try to fetch the output project.exe and project.pdb for debugging`. So if the debugging works well(those changes being applied), the output project.exe should also work without any issues(changes applied).

See this(for C++, similar situation with C#, VB):

[image]

This error message comes when VS debug engine can't find the output .exe, that's why I say if the changes are applied during debugging, it actually indicates the changes have been applied to your .exe file.

Let me name the project which outputs the .exe ProjectA, other projects in your solution are B,C,D. Here are two directions you can check:

If the code changes you mean is **in Project A**:

1. Right click project A in Solution Explorer=>Properties, check the value of your `Output Directory`(C++) or `Output path in build tab`(C#), it represents where the output .exe will actually exist, and VS debug engine will fetch the .exe in this path.

So make sure you tested the .exe in this path instead of old versions from other locations.

If the code changes you mean is **in B,C,D**, and A depends on B,C,D:

1. In most of the time VS will help copy the assemblies from B,C,D into A's bin folder, but I'm not sure if something's wrong with your environment which breaks this. You should make sure all the assemblies in your bin folder are **updated**.

I think this issue comes from your project instead of IDE(create a new simple project to check if the issue occurs in it). And in which way did you check if the changes are applied? Make sure you use the same way no matter checking during debugging or checking the `.exe`.

**Updated:**

According to Sandesh, this issue could be resolved by a **clean**(clean 
 old versions completely) rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project and click property, in General page, set "Enable Managed Incremental Build" as "Yes". It will replace the old exe file after every builds.